# JBehave doesn't recognize steps, but does load the steps file

Tags: jbehave

With a different test runner (the annotation based one) the steps get picked up and run.  The annotation based approach doesn't seem to support a steps factory though, so I swapped models.  Now, it will load the steps class (some visible things happen when the constructor is called) but it won't recognize any of the steps inside it.  Any ideas?  Here's my embedder class:

public class LoginAcceptanceFull extends JUnitStories {

```
private final CrossReference xref = new CrossReference();

public LoginAcceptanceFull() {
    configuredEmbedder().embedderControls().doGenerateViewAfterStories(true)
    .doIgnoreFailureInStories(true).doIgnoreFailureInView(true).useThreads(2)
    .useStoryTimeoutInSecs(60);
}

@Override
public Configuration configuration() {
    Class<? extends Embeddable> embeddableClass = this.getClass();
    Properties viewResources = new Properties();
    viewResources.put("decorateNonHtml", "true");
    // Start from default ParameterConverters instance
    ParameterConverters parameterConverters = new ParameterConverters();
    // factory to allow parameter conversion and loading from external
    // resources (used by StoryParser too)
    ExamplesTableFactory examplesTableFactory = new ExamplesTableFactory(new LocalizedKeywords(),
            new LoadFromClasspath(embeddableClass), parameterConverters);
    // add custom converters
    parameterConverters.addConverters(new DateConverter(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")),
            new ExamplesTableConverter(examplesTableFactory));

    return new MostUsefulConfiguration()
            .useStoryControls(new StoryControls().doDryRun(false).doSkipScenariosAfterFailure(false))
            .useStoryLoader(new LoadFromURL())
            .useStoryParser(new RegexStoryParser(examplesTableFactory))
            .useStoryPathResolver(new UnderscoredCamelCaseResolver())
            .useStoryReporterBuilder(
                    new StoryReporterBuilder()
                            .withCodeLocation(CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(embeddableClass))
                            .withDefaultFormats().withPathResolver(new ResolveToPackagedName())
                            .withViewResources(viewResources).withFormats(org.jbehave.core.reporters.Format.HTML, 
                                    org.jbehave.core.reporters.Format.TXT, org.jbehave.core.reporters.Format.XML)
                            .withFailureTrace(true).withFailureTraceCompression(true).withCrossReference(xref))
            .useParameterConverters(parameterConverters)
            .useStepPatternParser(new RegexPrefixCapturingPatternParser("%")) 
            .useStepMonitor(xref.getStepMonitor());
    }

@Override
public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory(){
    return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), new LoginSteps());
}

@Override 
protected List<String> storyPaths(){
    String codeLocation = org.jbehave.core.io.CodeLocations.codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass()).getFile();
    return new StoryFinder().findPaths(codeLocation, asList("**/login_trial.story"),
                asList(""), "file:" + codeLocation);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I found it.  Right here was the culprit:

```
.useStepPatternParser(new RegexPrefixCapturingPatternParser("%"))
```

It was causing JBehave to not recognize the @Given annotations and so JBehave assumed everything needed a step and listed them all as pending (or skipped them because they were missing the @Given step).  Once I pulled that part of the configuration everything was cool.